# Maven cannot find symbol error with intern java files

Tags: java, maven, symbols

I'm coding a Test file(src/test/java) for my maven project.
The problem is the following:

intern file cannot be found: (is in the src/main/java folder)

```
[ERROR] /D:/SWT A1/jmjrst/src/test/java/Test.java:[6,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Generator
[ERROR] location: class Test
```

I already looked up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23351450/3906077) but I don't really understand how to configure the surefire plugin properly to exclude something.
I don't even know how what exclude is doing? Normally it should remove files from usage of the surefire plugin, am I right? But what is the purpose behind that?

my surefireplugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "intern file cannot be found"? Maybe the `Generator.java` file is not not in the right package directory.

Comment: my structure is the following: `src/main/java/org/jis/generator/Generator.java` and `src/test/java/Test.java` somehow the Test file can't access the Generator file

Comment: In that case `Generator` must be a `public` class.

Comment: That's why you should put the unit tests into the same package as the original class. So you can write a test for a class which is only visible within a package.